# How to expand a tuple with another value in Python?

Tags: python, opencv

Even though there are many questions regarding tuples, I've not found the proper way to do this.

I'm using python an OpenCV. I want to initialize a black image which is the same size as another image I'm working on. I do this in a function. So my function looks like this:

```
def myfunc(size):
   nsize = [];
   nsize.append(size[0])
   nsize.append(size[1])
   nsize.append(3);
   black_img = np.zeros(nsize,np.uint8)
```

When I call it, I call it like this

```
myfunc(base_image.shape)
```

In my func I create a new list (because shape gives an unmutable tuple) and append the values of size and the the 3 which represents the number of channels in a opencv image.

Is this the right way to do it? Or is there another way to expand the tuple?

Comment: An opencv image is not always 3 channels. You can have any number of channels, but typically it is between 1-4 channels. You could also create a new image by multiplying the original image by zero: `black_img = img * 0`. Doing it this way will ensure that the black image always has the same number of channels as the original.

Comment: You can also use `np.zeros_like()` and pass the shape of the image.

Comment: Thanks. I need the 3 channels because I use draw contours which requires a color image.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
black_img = np.zeros(size + (3,), np.uint8)
```

Comment: I'm new in python, so please bare with me. That is basically creating a new tuple by appending (because of the +) a 3 to the existing tuple?

Comment: @aarelovich exactly

Comment: @aarelovich That's right, is kind of concatenating two tuples. Note that the `,` after the `3` is important, one-element tuples in Python must include this comma (to differentiate it from just a parenthesized expression).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "expand" a tuple obviously since tuples are immutables, but you can create a new tuple by concatenating two or more tuples:

```
>>> t1 = (1, 2, 3)
>>> t2 = (0, 0, 0)
>>> t = t1 + t2
>>> t
(1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: `t1 += ("a","b","c")`

Comment: Add single items and multiple items. `t1 += ("a",)` or `t1 += ("a","b","c")`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to go to the extent of writing a four-lined code when it can be done in a single line

1. You can pass the shape of the image as it is to `np.zeros()`:

   ```
   new_image = np.zeros(old_image.shape, np.uint8)
   ```
2. You can also use `np.zeros_like()`:

   ```
   im = cv2.imread('apple.png', 1)

   im.shape
   Out[213]: (369, 369, 3)

   black = np.zeros_like(im)

   black.shape
   Out[215]: (369, 369, 3)
   ```

Comment: If I go with option 1, will it be a 3 channel image?

Comment: The number of channels will be with respect to the image passed. If the image is a 2-channeled image it will create a 2-channeled image and the same goes for 3 and 4-channeled images also. Give it a try!